# getted data is only null in apollo-client / apollo-server & useSubscription

Tags: apollo, publish-subscribe, apollo-client, apollo-server

I try use pubsub in apollo server & apollo client. but subscribed data is only null.

client dependency

```
 "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.5",
 "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
 "apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.20",
 "graphql": "^15.0.0",
 "react": "^16.13.1",
 "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
 "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
 "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
 "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
 "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.16",
 "typescript": "~3.7.2"
```

server dependency

```
  "apollo-server": "^2.14.1",
  "graphql": "^15.0.0",
  "merge-graphql-schemas": "^1.7.8",
  "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
  "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
  "typescript": "^3.9.3"
```

// apolloClient.ts

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache, split } from 'apollo-boost'

import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws'
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities'

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: 'ws://localhost:4000/graphql',
  options: {
    reconnect: true
  }
})

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000'
})

const link = split(
  // split based on operation type
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
      definition.operation === 'subscription'
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink,
)

const cache = new InMemoryCache()
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: cache,
  link: link,
})

export default client
```

// subscribe.ts

```
const ON_PUT_UNIT = gql`
  subscription onPutUnit($code: String!) {
    onPutUnit(code: $code)
  }
`
const onPutResult = useSubscription(
    ON_PUT_UNIT,
    { variables: {
      code: code,
    }}
  )

// in is only null!!
console.log('subscribe', onPutResult)
```

-server-
onPutUnit.ts

```
type Subscription {
  onPutUnit(code: String!): Room
}

import { pubsub } from '@src/index'
const { withFilter } = require('apollo-server')
export default {
  Subscription: {
    onPutUnit: {
      subscribe: withFilter(
       () => pubsub.asyncIterator(['PUT_UNIT']),
       (payload: any, variables: any) => {
         // no problem in payload & variable data 
         return payload.code === variables.code
       }
      ) 
    }
  },
}
```

putUnit.ts

```
type Mutation {
  putUnit(code: String!, x: Int!, y: Int!, userName: String!): Room!
}

export default {
  Mutation: {
    putUnit: async (_: any, args: args) => {
      const { code, x, y, userName } = args
      const room = findRoom(code)
      console.log(room) // no problem. normal data.
      pubsub.publish('PUT_UNIT', room)
      return room
    },
  },
}
```

Is it some problem? subscribe event is normally reached to client when publish. but data is is only null. I can't fine the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only specified a `subscribe` function for `onPutUnit`, without specifying a `resolve` function. That means the field utilizes the default resolver.

The default resolver just looks for a property with the same name as the field on the parent object (the first parameter passed to the resolver) and returns that. If there is no property on the parent object with the same name as the field, then the field resolves to null. The parent object is the value the parent field resolved to. For example, if we have a query like this:

```
{
  user {
    name
  }
}
```

whatever the resolver for `user` returns will be the parent value provided to the resolver for `name` (if `user` returns a Promise, it's whatever the Promise resolved to).

But what about `user`? It has no parent field because it's a root field. In this case, `user` is passed the `rootValue` you set when initializing the ApolloServer (or `{}` if you didn't).

With subscriptions, this works a bit differently because whatever value you `publish` is actually passed to the resolver as the root value. That means you can take advantage of the default resolver by publishing an object with a property that matches the field name:

```
pubsub.publish('PUT_UNIT', { onPutUnit: ... })
```

if you *don't* do that, though, you'll need to provide a `resolve` function that transforms the payload you published. For example, if we do:

```
pubsub.publish('PUT_UNIT', 'FOOBAR')
```

Then our resolver map needs to look something like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Subscription: {
    onPutUnit: {
      subscribe: ...,
      resolve: (root) => {
        console.log(root) // 'FOOBAR'
        // return whatever you want onPutUnit to resolve to
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: I got it. It should be return in resolve function. Thank you! you save me.